# Looking for Flash Android AS3 tutorials

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm looking for a good tutorial website that teachers the functions of Android with Flash, AS3 isn't the problem, its the AS3 functions that interact with Android I can't find any tutorials on. If anyone can help that would be cool.

Canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous resources from Adobe.

- [Adobe Mobile and Devices Cookbook](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/mobile)
- [Using Flash Builder 4.5 to package applications for Google Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html)
- [Developing Mobile Applications with Flex 4.6 and Flash Builder 4.6](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/index.html)
- [Native extensions for Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)

Look at [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/show/adc-presents/) or [Flash Platform API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) for AIR and mobile specific packages.